# VBA to select Listbox value based on table value

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm certain this is a basic issue, but I can't find an answer. It may be wording my question poorly.

I have the listbox on a form linked to a table. On that table I have a field called "Functional Area." This field automatically gets populated based on the user's office symbol.

The listbox lists all of the functional areas.

I want the listbox to automatically start with the user's functional area selected. The user can select a different functional area from there.

This is my code, it works, but obviously selecting the 0 value of the listbox doesn't get me what I'm looking for.

```
'Detect Office
Me.Office = DLookup("[Office]", "*Local - User List - Active Directory", "[UserID] =" & "'" & Me.UserID & "'")

'Detect Function
Me.Function = DLookup("[Functional Area]", "0 - Active User - Funtional Area")
Me.[Functional Area] = Me.Function

'Set Listbox Value
Me!LetterSourceListBox.Selected(0) = True
Me.Refresh
```

Is there a way I can find the row number of the item in the listbox and then select that?

Thank you,
-Stephen

Comment: `Me.LetterSourceListBox.Value = StartingValue`? Or maybe `For Each Item In Me.LetterSourceListBox.List: If <expression> Then Me.LetterSourceListBox.Value = Item`?

Comment: Is UserID a text field? The second DLookup needs Office criteria `DLookup("[Functional Area]", "0 - Active User - Funtional Area", "Office='" & Me.Office & "'")`. If listbox is bound to field, should just populate field and that should show the selected item in list. Life would be less frustrating if you did not use spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention.

Comment: I can't believe I missed the bound field thing! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Per June7's comments, I just needed to make the functional area a bound field and everything works nicely!

Cheers!